# How to set input type date's default value to today?using ASP net core 7.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

```
<input type="date"  id="ngaydk" value="01/02/2023">
```

[image]

```
<input type="date"  id="ngaydk" value="01/02/2023">
```

or

```
ViewData["greeting2"] = "01/01/2023";
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="ngaydk" value=@ViewData["greeting2"]>
```

resual :

[image]

I want show value "01/02/2023" at load page but
not show value "01/02/2023" helpme!

Comment: The value in `input type="date"` is always in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, no matter how it's displayed. That's a *very* good thing, because it means you don't have to worry about formats when reading or setting date values. ASP.NET Core can't change how browsers treat the `input` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Format for a date value is YYYY-MM-DD

```html
<input type="date" value="2023-02-01">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an asp.net core web application and this is what I have in my `index.cshtml`

```
<div>
    <label>date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="ngaydk"   />
    <input type="date" id="ngaydk2"   />
    <input type="date" id="mydate"   />
    @Html.TextBox("date1", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), new { type = "date" })
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("mydate").valueAsDate = new Date();
    console.info(document.getElementById("mydate").value);
</script>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            console.info("value is :" + $("#ngaydk2").val());
            $("#ngaydk2").val('@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")');
            console.info("value is :" + $("#ngaydk2").val());
        });
    </script>
}
```

[image]

Comment: I test in Chrome and Edge, have the same behavior in page...